# Can I simply check the unicode or UTF-8 mapping of character to infer the language?

Tags: computational-linguistics, machine-translation

I am given a language detection problem. I was wondering if it could be solved just by looking at the encoding map of characters used and decide which language it is. Is there too much overlap of characters across languages?

Answer (score 1):

Most scripts are used by more than one language. The Latin alphabet is shared by English, German, French, etc. The Arabic script is also used by Farsi and Urdu. Chinese (Han) characters are borrowed by Japanese, and sometimes also Vietnamese and Korean. The Hebrew script is also used by Yiddish. And so on and so forth.

Now, some particular characters within a script might be distinctive, like *ñ* being a good indication of Spanish, *ß* of German, etc. But not every language has distinctive characters like this—there's no letter used by English that isn't also used by half a dozen European languages, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good language detectors out there (and some open software implementations of them as well), but going for the character set is not a good approach for language detection at all.

Good language detectors can detect the language quite reliable for rather short fragments of text. Such short text fragment don't exhibit the full character set (e.g., they may not show an x or a q for an English sample).

Good language detectors use frequency information and character n-grams, and also short and frequent words for their analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Using a character set encoding (if such a thing is built in to the file) is kind of a gamble. A person might use ISO 8859-13 because it includes some relevant characters in one set; and really, if a person uses various UTF's, you don't learn much at all. On the other hand, you could narrow the search by picking just the languages that use the attested characters in the corpus. For example, the letter "ө" appears in languages that adopted Cyrillic writing such as Mongolian, various Turkic languages and some Tungusic ones. The practical challenge would be checking all of the potential languages that use that  letter. Ewen does, though the Wiki article on ө does not know that. If you also find ӈ, then you have an increased probability that the language is Ewen. But it could be Ket, so the search continues. Certain letters such as á are so common as to be very un-informative. As far as I know, ŧ is used in only three languages – North Saami, SENĆOŦEN, and [Hualapai](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Sumiaz/Maricopa). SENĆOŦEN is easy because everything is written in upper case.